# How can i write to a text file while replacing number on same line?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is my code in a timer tick event interval ever minute.

```
postsCounter += 1;
label2.Text = postsCounter.ToString();
label2.Visible = true;
w.WriteLine(postsCounter.ToString());
```

w is a StreamWriter

But instead adding every minute a new line like

1
2
3
4
5

I want that then ext write to the text file will rpelace the last number. And not to add a new line or a number near it but to replace it like a counter. So in the end when i will stop the timer and watch the text file i will see one line with the last number counted.

Forgot to mention i did instance for the StreamWrite in the top of form1 then in constructor i'm writing once a line of DateTime.Now to the text file then i want to add an empty/space line then to write the numbers and in the end when i finish writing the numbers to add another empty/space line then to write the DateTime.Now again.

In top of form1

```
int postsCounter = 0;
StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"e:\posts.txt");
```

In constructor

```
label4.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
w.WriteLine(label4.Text.ToString());
label5.Visible = false;
label2.Visible = false;
```

In the timer tick event

```
sent = true;
            postsCounter += 1;
            label2.Text = postsCounter.ToString();
            label2.Visible = true;
            w.WriteLine(postsCounter.ToString());
            if (postsCounter == 720)
            {
                label5.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                label5.Visible = true;
                w.WriteLine(label5.Text.ToString());
                w.Close();
                timer1.Stop();
            }
```

Comment: Why don't you write out the counter only one time  when you stop the timer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *System.IO.File.WriteAllText* method to replace file content on each tick. For example:

```
postsCounter += 1;
label2.Text = postsCounter.ToString();
label2.Visible = true;
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, postsCounter.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a different method like `File.WriteAllText`, which will replace file contents every time you call it.

```
File.WriteAllText("log.txt", postsCounter.ToString());
```